# How can i add minuts in current Datetime in excel with the help of formulla?

Tags: excel-2007

I have a excel sheet in which i want to add 10 minute.

Example of output as :

Actual Time is : 10/2/2013 12:30:00 , so in this time i want to add 10 minute so i need output as 10/2/2013 12:40:00.

Please provide me formula for this.

Many Thanks,

Tausif.

Comment: Dear all ..plz reply the answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is covered in Excel Help:

if you use the TIME function, then `=A2+TIME(0,10,0)` will add 10 minutes to the time in cell `A2`; `+TIME(1,0,0)` adds 1 hour, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (assuming your date data is in the C3 cell)

`=C3+TIME(0,10,0)`

The first parameter is for hours, second is for minutes, third is for seconds.

Comment: Ant @ Thanks Dear for the help :-)